# i can't start react_app container on aws server Exited (0)

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, server, dockerfile

## i can't start react_app container on aws server Exited (0)

## I have this issue where my react app won’t start in docker. It reads “starting the development server” but it does nothing after that. Any ideas on what I might be missing please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LunBb.png)

## this is my dockercompose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build: 
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - "./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
  react:
    build: ./react
    container_name: react_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
```

## this is docker file

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --force
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```